# Delete Rows in Word Table according to the font style

Tags: vba, ms-word, rows, cells

i am still trying to fix a problem with a table in word. In my table are three columns and many rows. In the row an explanatory text is written in italic. Now I want to delete rows in the tables of my worddocument where the font is italic.
I tried to use the macro recorder but it wont work. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read in the [help] how to ask effective questions on the site. You're expected to show your efforts (code) and explain HOW they don't work and where you're stuck. As it stands, your question is "too broad" and likely to get closed.

Answer (score 0):

For that you might use a macro like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim r As Long, Rng As Range
With Selection
  If .Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then Exit Sub
  With .Tables(1)
    For r = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
      Set Rng = .Cell(r, 1).Range
      With Rng
        .End = .End - 1
        If .Font.Italic = True Then .Rows(1).Delete
      End With
    Next
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

where the 1 in .Cell(r, 1).Range indicates the column # of the italicised text.